# How to pull ALL from database and limit as opposed to specific id?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know this is simple php,however I am having great trouble getting my logic written out with codeigniter.

I am trying to pull the 12 most recent users and display their info in a view. I have made a 'created_on' field in my database table to track activity of signing up.

When I specify an id in my controller I am able to pull results that I'm passing from my model to my controller and then my view, however it's only pulling one user like so.

MODEL:

```
public function newest_members()
      {

            $session = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active' && id = $user_id ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 12");

            if($query->num_rows()==1)
            {
               $data = $query->result_array();
               return $data;
            }else{
            return array();
        }

    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function dashboard() 
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->load->model('account_model');
        $this->load->model('community_model');
        $user = $this->account_model->user();
        $data['user'] = $user;
        $newest_members = $this->community_model->newest_members();
        $data['newest_members'] = $newest_members;
        $data['main_content'] = 'account/dashboard';
        $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
    }
```

VIEW:

```
<?php 
    foreach($newest_members as $nm)
     {
         echo $nm['first_name']; echo "<br />"; echo $nm['last_name'];
     }
 ?>
```

That is pulling the result of the NEWEST member and the one that is signed in. However I want to pull ALL signed in or not so I was trying something like this with my model:

```
public function newest_members()
      {


            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 12");
            // OR YOU CAN USE THE BELOW
            // $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY `created_on` DESC LIMIT 12");

            // YOU ALSO MIGHT WHAT TO ADD WHERE `status` = 'active' (or whatever applies for your db table)

            // EITHER SPIT OUT RESULTS OR EMPTY ARRAY
            if($query->num_rows()==1)
            {
               $data = $query->result_array();
               return $data;
            }else{
            return array();
        }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 12 FROM users WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY created_on DESC
```

I'M using mssql for this,, try it if it help

Answer (score 0):

The codeigniter num_rows() function does not return a boolean value but rather the number of results fetched from the database. There fore your model should insead have :

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

see [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You want to pull the 12 newest active members? You had it right.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active' ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 12
```

Also, you don't want to check if just one row is returning. You want to check if more than zero rows are returning. You need to do this instead:

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $data = $query->result_array();
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your using codeigniter it has a wonderful feature called active record that makes working with a database much easier and more secure then writing raw queries as strings which could result in SQL injection. Here is your function below both utilizing active record and returning the results your expecting.

```
public function newest_members()
{
    //Select the 12 newest users
    $result = $this->db->where('status', 'active')->order_by('created_on', 'desc')->limit(12)->get('users');

    //If results are found return an array otherwise return an empty array
    return ($result->num_rows() > 0) ? $result->result_array() : array();
}
```